# Is there a way to burn an iso from a dual-layer onto a single-layer dvd

Tags: linux, dvd-burning

I wanna make a copy of this dvd movie that I have. I've used dvdbackup to get a VIDEO_TS folder, then i used genisoimage to make an ISO file, and the iso plays fine when opened with VLC. However, the source is a dual-layer dvd and thus the ISO is over 8gb. is there a way to burn this onto a single-layer dvd so that i may watch it on my dvd player? And I'm using linux, btw...I don't have Windows or Macintosh.

Comment: No, single layer has half the space dual layer, nothing you can do to change this. Most dvd players read DL discs, strange yours does not.

Comment: my dvd player does read them. i just wanted to make a copy, but all i have are single layer dvds. i read that it might be possible via compression. some people had mentioned software for windows that would do it.

Comment: OK, there is, here is one example....https://download.cnet.com/DVDSanta/3000-2646_4-10291136.html

Comment: but that's for windows.

Comment: There are bound to be some for Linux, it was just an example that it was possible. Start using Google.